# this and $(this) in widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-widget

What do this and $(this) mean inside a widget method like create?

For example, Having a widget like this,

```
$.widget("sample.CustomWidget", {
options:{
},
_create: function(){
// Here what do this and $(this) mean
}
});
```

Thanks in advance,

-Raja.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "widget"? A plugin using jQueryUI's widget factory, or just a regular plugin?

Comment: `this` refers to a function's context. RTFM: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It basically depends on the caller of the _create method... anyway:

- `this` refers to the 'owner' of the Function
- `$(this)` is the above object wrapped into a jQuery object

see also:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1838-Wrapping-The-Window-Object-In-A-jQuery-Wrapper.htm

Comment: Yeah in general terms, but in the context of a widget "this" is a JQuery widget itself, as opposed to the wrapper.

Comment: @mattytommo, could you tell the exact explanation

Comment: Well basically what I said was, as long as you're not calling the _create method yourself and you're letting JQuery do that for you, then "this" will always be the widget object, if you try debugging you can do this.widgetName, this.widgetEventPrefix etc, where as when wrapped into a jQuery object it's no longer a jQuery widget object, it's just a generic jQuery object, therefore you can't access any of the widget object properties (widgetName etc.) :)

Answer (score 3):

Within an *event handler* of a standard jQuery UI-style widget, `this` will refer to the DOM element related to the event, `$(this)` creates a jQuery wrapper around `this`, and the DOM element (again) is available as `this`.

But when your widget *functions* are called, typically `this` refers to the jQuery object on which the function was called, not a specific DOM element. You then operate on the matched set of elements within that jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

In a method integrated with jQuery:

```
$.fn.yourFunction = function() {
  // ...
};
```

the value of `this` is the jQuery object itself. There's no reason, therefore, to wrap `this` with another call to jQuery, though it doesn't hurt.

In a callback to an event handler:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
  // ...
});
```

the value of `this` is the target DOM element of the event, or the target object if the event is triggered on something other than the actual DOM.

In other jQuery callback situations, like `.each()` for example, the value of `this` is generally determined by the nature of the jQuery object.

The upshot of all that is that inside an integrated-with-jQuery function (first sample), you generally *don't* wrap `this` in another call to jQuery; it's already a jQuery object. In all other cases, if you want to use `this` with jQuery facilities, you *do* have to wrap it.

Answer (score 1):

In that context, "this" is the actual JQuery widget object, which allows you to query things such as widgetName, widgetEventPrefix etc, whereas "$(this)" is just the JQuery object for "this", which you can't get the widget properties using.

Comment: From the posted source you cannot tell what type of callers the _create function will have, so this and $(this) could not be the same...

Comment: It's a private function though? _create cannot be invoked from an external caller can it not?

Comment: Raja's code could be referred to that factory: http://ajpiano.com/widgetfactory/ ...anyway you cannot assume that _create won't be called as an event callback (and in that case 'this' could potentially be whatever), nor that inside _create you won't have any other function. So, again, it basically depends on where these statements are placed ;)

Comment: Okay fair enough, I agree as he hasn't specified the caller, you can't be too sure. +1 to your answer for that then, but don't I get a return +1 for mine? :P

Answer (score 1):

this represents the contructor you are in. For example in a click event, the dom element being clicked, in a function the constructor of function;

```
function test{
    this.b = "hello jupiter";
}
var a = new test();
alert(a.b);
```

Acctually there is nothing special with $(this). There is a function called $ and "this" is it's parameter, like alert;

```
$(this);
//just like
alert("some string);
```